# Why are checkmarks not being displayed when UITableView.allowsMultipleSelection is enabled?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in an iOS5.1 app where I set

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection=YES;
```

The Apple documentation states "When the value of this property is YES, a check mark is placed next to each row that is tapped. Tapping the row again removes the check mark.".

I am able to select multiple rows as the background is set to Blue. However, no checkmarks are displayed. Does the checkmark need to be set as shown below in didSelectRowAtIndexPath because I am using custom UITableViewCells?

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution to this problem? Please let me know.

Comment: Same question as AlexR here. The answers below of "I had the same problem so I decided to ignore it and reimplement the feature myself" aren't satisfying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do the checkmarks manually in my uitableviewcell subclasses. You are going to have to do the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark manually in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and keep a track of which one is selected. I would recommend something like so:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableview cellAtIndex:indexPath];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

note: I did not test this, but should give you the basic idea. Let me know if you have any questions. Did you try using a default uitableviewcell and see if it did the checkmark? I would not think a subclass would have a problem, as long as you are not modifying in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I had done previous, but it seems from the Apple docs it would happen automatically in iOS5+. I have implemented it this way now. However, there may be a bug that I am trying to track down related to the checkmark being displayed automatically in certain situations.

Comment: Ah, alright. Yeah I agree it would seem from the docs that the checkmarks should be handled automatically. Maybe it is just implying that would be the proper guidelines? Anyway, again I agree it is a bug or the docs should be reworded.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: in addition to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

}

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

}

Comment: If you do that the checkbox will show up on the right rather than left.